# Receiving Messages sent from Facebook BOT

Tags: php, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm currently developing a Facebook Messenger Bot with PHP, but i can't receive the message sent to the Bot using (php://input)

```
$userMessage=file_get_contents("php://input");
```

The $userMessage variable is always empty. But i can see any message sent to the bot from the ngrok web interface.
Please see my code below.

```
$message=file_get_contents("php://input");
$data=json_decode($message,true);
```

Please see the response from the server below.

```
{
"object": "page",
"entry": [
    {
        "id": "2081173465260168",
        "time": 1535037661116,
        "messaging": [
            {
                "sender": {
                    "id": "1935422053189934"
                },
                "recipient": {
                    "id": "2081173465260168"
                },
                "timestamp": 1535037659856,
                "message": {
                    "mid": "NV5F2SEvBt_kiByHhOHOOxGuHnFsxPmmjMlkwErkhywnh8GyDCcggY9L6S8zg1V5BCO7yd2CkPVsE6AVAx7TFg",
                    "seq": 20758,
                    "text": "Hello bot"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: You may want to add some additional code if you want people to help you here...

Comment: Hi @Alberto, Thank you for the response, i'm just trying to retrieve the message sent to the Bot.` $message=file_get_contents("php://input");
 $data=json_decode($message,true);` That is the only line of code, the bot works because i can see the message log on ngrok server. I just don't know why i can't retrieve it with php

Comment: Your code isn't complete, you need to add more code. Here is what I found on the web as an example: https://dzone.com/articles/facebook-messenger-bot

Comment: @unixmiah using your example, here is the line of code that is not working 
// handle bot's anwser
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);. The first few lines are irrelevant if  you have verified your bot, which i have. I only need to process the message i receive bot file_get_contents('php://input'). is not working

Comment: @unixmiah I have added the response from the server, i just need to pick the input in my PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out after few hours, the problem was a trailing slash at the end of the URL. Thank you guys